# How can we apply desired CSS to the complete ionic app frame

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app that is design specific to Mobile phones only but can run on Tablets too. I want to restrict it to max-width & max-height so that when app is opened on Tabs or larger screens, the view should remain like a mobile phone view.

[image]

Now this can be achieved by applying following CSS to content div on individual page.

```
.contain-in-phone{
display: block;
max-width: 375px;
max-height: 667px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border: 3px solid black;
text-align: center;
}
```

but there are so many screens that it wouldn't be possible.

Can we apply this to the root level CSS of the application or can we achieve this using some configuration in ionic platform so that all pages are shown like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed on partially achieving the requirement.
The App can be centred horizontally on screen dynamically.
Open the file \src\index.html

Ionic App runs in the  tags. You can do whatever you want to these tags and the parent of your will respond accordingly. I centered this tag and achieved the screenshot like view.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you are looking for...
Ideally an app should be responsive for all devices.

Assuming that you want your screen to appear as in the image above.
Instead of applying the CSS to content div on individual page by using id, you can directly do it by using the tag.

```
ion-content{
    display: block;
    max-width: 375px;
    max-height: 667px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 3px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

By doing this, you don't have to write the code again and again for each page. Although, it is not recommended to apply css by tag name, you can do it if referring the div by id is too tiresome for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your body tag add a class (.yourclassname) and then write this css

```
body.yourclassname ion-view {
    max-width: 420px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 667px;
}
```

If you want to change background color then add your color in your defined class

```
body.yourclassname {
    background-color: red;
}
```